# HD 4850 on a 80+ 400W PSU

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

Would a [400W PSU](http://www.emag.ro/surse/sursa-sirtec-400w-atx-23-pfc-activ--pHPC-400-G12S) be able to run a 4850HD 512MB GDDR3 256bit GPU? The current build is:

- [Gigabyte M61PME-S2](http://www.emag.ro/placi_baza/placa-de-baza-gigabyte-m61pme-s2-socket-am2--pM61PME-S2)
- [AMD Athlon 64 X2 5000+](http://www.emag.ro/procesoare/procesor-amd-athlon-64-x2-5000-brisbane-socket-am2-box--pADO5000DOBOX-ADA5000CSBOX)
- [Gigabyte GF9600GT 512MB GDDR3, 256bit](http://www.emag.ro/placi_video/placa-video-gigabyte-gf9600gt-512mb-gddr3-256bit-hdcp-pci-e--pNX96T512H)
- [2GB DDR2 800MHz](http://www.emag.ro/memorii/kit-memorie-mushkin-2x-1gb-sp2-6400-retail--p996529)
- [HDD Western Digital 160GB](http://www.emag.ro/hard_disk-uri/hdd-western-digital-160gb-7200rpm-ide--pWD1600AAJB)

I know it's old, I'm planning on upgrading, but for now, I just need to know if the PSU would support the HD 4850 GPU.

Thank you.

Comment: This request is far too specific to be useful to people. You should read the existing post on [how to calculate power for a new PC](http://superuser.com/questions/9946/how-to-choose-a-ups-calculate-power-for-a-new-pc) to help you determine the power required for your setup. There's also an excellent blog post on PSU's scheduled for a couple weeks from now, so keep your eyes out for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have no problems using a 400 watt PSU with that list of equipment.  I have a very similar rig but with just a 350 watt PSU.  This PC consumes only about 65 watts from the wall outlet at idle, and about 110 watts playing HiDef videos.  There is no indication that the PSU is being taxed, since these numbers indicate that only about a quarter (25%) of the PSU's output capacity is used..