# How can I evaluate how much power (from power supply) is needed based on PC configuration?

Tags: power-supply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to choose a UPS / calculate power for a new PC](https://superuser.com/questions/9946/how-to-choose-a-ups-calculate-power-for-a-new-pc)

It seems to be a common question here, but I want to know, based on a configuration (processor, used memory modules, video chip, number of fans, etc), which is the better power supply to fulfill an specific need. Is there any calculation I can do for knowing that?

The popular knowledge just says to use certain power supply wattages deppending of your user profile ( heavy user -> 500w, heavy gamer -> 700w, etc), and I think this is very inaccurate.

By the way, my second question is, yes, a recommendation.
I recently bought a Intel i7, a 2TB commom HD, a single 4gb module (planing to upgrade to 4x4gb), a GeForce GT210 512mb, with 2 extra fans and a 500w power supply weren't sufficient (The PC was shutting down seconds after it was powered on, and shutting down again(eternal loop) - I think this is a power supply issue). And I will first know how many watts I need to serve my configuration before trying another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of our very own Super Users, Berk98, has written a very detailed blog post on how to select the right PSU. You can find it on our own blog! - [5 Ways of Finding the Right Power Supply](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/28/5-ways-of-finding-the-right-power-supply/).

Comment: Thanks Simon! Now I see that I didn't found any duplicate of my question because I used the wrong terms. Sorry!

Comment: @MarcelodeAssis its all good! Glad we got your question resolved!