# Will 250 watt be enough for my setup?

Tags: virtualization, power-supply, windows-8-preview, home-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to choose a UPS / calculate power for a new PC](https://superuser.com/questions/9946/how-to-choose-a-ups-calculate-power-for-a-new-pc)

**Introduction**

So, I did post this before but had the question deleted before I could read why. This time I've elaborated it a bit and added the figures from my own research. I did also post this on serverfault but are trying to have it deleted from there since this seems to be a more appropriate place for this question. Sorry for any inconvenience, I'm just trying to get some help and this should be an interesting question for a lot of people out there.

**Question**

I'm planning to build a virtualization server for home usage. I'm a developer and do need some playing grounds.

The current setup is

- Motherboard: ASUS P8Z77-M PRO Z77 S-1155 M-ATX IVY
- Memory: 4 x CORSAIR 8GB DDR3 VENGEANCE PC3-12800 1600MHZ CL10 (32 GB total)
- CPU: INTEL CORE I7 3770 3.4GHZ 8MB S-1155 IVY
- Harddrive 1: OCZ AGILITY 3 2.5" 90GB SSD SATA/600 MLC
- Harddrive 2: SEAGATE BARRACUDA 1TB 7200RPM SATA/600 64MB

The HD1 will contain the base OS that is Win 2K8R2, HD2 will contain the virtual machines.

This is all there will be in this box, not even a USB-keyboard will normally be attached, neither any gfx card other than the built-in. No CD/DVD.

I did find a very nice HTPC with a 250-270 watts power supply that should be perfect for this project. The question, do you think the power will be enough?

***Some figures I have***

- The CPU that is said to consume approx 77 W
- The segate harddrive should consume something like 8-12 W
- The OCZ SSD drive is about 1-3 W
- The motherboard should not use much unless the graphics is used, and I will almost never use it, am I wrong?
- The power consumption for the ram memory is hard to find, I figured that something like 100W is required when in full usage but I might be wrong.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Comment: Old one probably shouldn't have been deleted - sorry about that. Basically, your question is a bit too specific, and we already have a good community FAQ on this. If somehow you find that the info there isn't sufficient for your needs, go ahead and edit this question (please don't make a new one) and put in what more you need to know. Then we can go from there.

Comment: Just a quick safety comment, "almost" isn't good enough. The instant you exceed your power supply's rated capacity, you run the risk of it blowing up as well as random failures. PSU's are the worst component to cut corners on. Don't do it.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/fx1me.png @Trikks

Comment: Just to sum things up; NO! You need a MUCH larger PSU. Never cheap out on this part, or you risk all your hardware!

Comment: `very nice HTPC` - links please! Really the quality of this will determine the quality of the PSU. As mentioned several times (this question and the last) the quality of the PSU usually matters more than the advertised wattage. Check paradroids comment on your old question - this system is going to be under constant 'quite high' load 24/7 so the PSU is one of the most important components. Personally i'd look at 350-400W just for peace of mind.