# What power supply do I need for this configuration?

Tags: power-supply

My computer's specifications is the following:

```
Gigabyte GA-Z97-D3H desktop motherboard
Intel Core i5 4690K s1150 BOX processor
Kingston 16GB 1600MHz DDR3 RAM Non-ECC CL11 Kit of 2
GIGABYTE GEFORCE GTX 960 GAMING 2GB GDDR5 128BIT PCI-E X16
Samsung 850 EVO series 250GB SATA3 2, 5 SSD
Western Digital Black 1TB hard disk
Cooler Master Hyper 103 processor cooler
```

And I have one extra 120mm fan on the back of the computer.

What power supply do I need for this configuration. I am absolutely sure that it will be FSP Hyper M, but is the 500 Watt model enough for this?

Comment: [related](http://superuser.com/q/9946/172747)

Answer (score 1):

I have similar components including a 120GB SSD drive. The power supply I use is the Corsair CS550M. Works very well and is semi modular. If you want a slightly better one I would suggest the Corsair RM650i or RM650x.

I have no idea about FSP Hyper M but I can assure you about Corsair. They have a warranty from about 5-7 years and my power supply has never failed me.

**EDIT** : My friend uses the FSP Hyper M and says that it can hold your configuration.

Comment: Thank you! But which FSP Hyper M does your friend use? The 500W, 600W or the 700W one?

Comment: @user230682 The 500W model will be sufficient.

Comment: @user230682 My friend uses the 500 Watt it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just last year I built a machine for a client using that CPU and mobo.  The TDP of the CPU is 88 watts, and the GPU may draw 120 watts.  Nvidia recommends 400 watts for systems with that graphics card.  The rest of the components you mentioned are negligible.

I cannot say that I've ever used a 'FSP' power supply, but if they do supply a minimum of their rated power then 500 watts will be plenty for your system.  My recommendation for your build is a 500 watt PSU from a good vendor, or 550-600 if otherwise.  This gives you plenty of headroom for overclocking and adding components, whereas a 400 watt PSU would likely be fine for your setup.

Links to the data sheets following:

http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-960/specifications

http://ark.intel.com/products/80811/Intel-Core-i5-4690K-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz

Comment: FSP are a major PSU manufacturer; they are used as an OEM by brands such as Antec and Silverstone. Graphics card manufacturers are usually conservative in their power supply capacity recommendations to account for PSUs of lesser quality.

Comment: That's wonderful, then my recommendation to take the 500 watt model the asker mentioned or a 400 watt sufficing stands.